# Set default value of text box to query result vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

I found this article [Set Default Value of Text Box to Query Result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187042/set-default-value-of-text-box-to-query-result)
I'm trying to use the following code, but I keep getting an error.  The name of the query is MaxNote and then Field retured in the query is MaxNote.

```
Public Function MaxNote()
       MaxNote = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("MaxNote").Fields("MaxNote")
End Function
```

Comment: In given link the using of DLookup function has max score? Maybe you should try this? Otherwise, you haven't provided error message and error description?

Comment: It is displaying #Error in the default value when the form is run...

Answer (score 1):

Use *DLookup* for such simple tasks, and note, that *DefaultValue* is text, and use *Nz* if MaxNote can be *Null*:

```
Me!YourTextbox.DefaultValue = Chr(34) & LTrim(Nz(Str(DLookup("MaxNote", "MaxNote")))) & Chr(34)
```

Comment: Thanks Gustav!  I got this to work!  I put =LTrim(Nz(Str(DLookup("MaxNote", "MaxNote")))) in the default value property for my text box.

Comment: Yes, that will work the same. If you feel so, then please mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Public Function MaxNote()
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("MaxNote") 
    rst.MoveFirst
    MaxNote = rst.Fields("MaxNote")
End Function
```

Try this, if you prefer rst opening, instead of DLookup

Comment: Empty recordset raises error on`.MoveFirst`, what is not handled.

Comment: That means there ia no records in rst. Too many assumptions for this approach

Answer (score 0):

Here an`On Error Resume Next`can be helpfull as an error indicates an empty result.

```vb
Public Function MaxNote() as Variant
       MaxNote = "" ' default return value for not records found. Can be NULL or 0 too
   On Error Resume Next ' if lookup fails code resumes next line, what is End Function (nothing happens)
       MaxNote = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("MaxNote").Fields("MaxNote") ' fetch the field from first row of recordset (standard after .OpenRecordSet() ), if no results an error is raised, but function resumes next line of code, what ends the function and still with MaxNote = "", the value if no records are found
End Function
```